# How to send table dropdown select fields to flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a table composed of three columns, a text and two other `select` fields.
When the user chooses an option from the dropdown `select`, I would like to send these data to flask.

I know I can make it work with `input`s but since I am working with `select`, I am not sure how I can send them back to flask.

This is my table:

```html
<div class="row" id="tablediv">
    <div class="col">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table"/>
    </div>
</div>


const office_cardgroups = data['cardgroups']
const office_doorgroups = data['doorgroups']

const table = document.getElementById("table");
const header = table.createTHead();
var row = header.insertRow(0);
row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "<b>Departments</b>";
row.insertCell(1).innerHTML =  "<b>Card Groups</b>";
row.insertCell(2).innerHTML =  "<b>Door Groups</b>";

{% for department in departments %}
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "{{ department.name }}";
    var row_cardgroup = '<td className="select"><select id="cardgroups_{{ department.id }}">'

    for (const [key, cardgroup] of Object.entries(office_cardgroups)) {
        var row_cardgroup = row_cardgroup + '<option value=' + cardgroup['id'] + '>'+ cardgroup['name']+'</option>'
    }
    row_cardgroup = row_cardgroup + '</select></td>'

    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = row_cardgroup

    var row_doorgroup = '<td className="select"><select id="cardgroups_{{ department.id }}">'

    for (const [key, doorgroup] of Object.entries(office_doorgroups)) {
        var row_doorgroup = row_doorgroup + '<option value=' + doorgroup['id'] + '>'+ doorgroup['name']+'</option>'
    }

    row_doorgroup = row_doorgroup +  '</selec></td>'

    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = row_doorgroup

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in the shared code:

- `table` tag is not self closing so it should be

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table"></table>
```

- Not sure where `data['cardgroups']` and `data['doorgroups']` are coming from, If they are coming from backend to `jinja` template then it should be wrapped with parenthesis `{{}}`
- Since you are writing javascript it should be inside `script` tag
- `id` should be unique across html right now we have 2 id with same name `cardgroups_{{ department.id }}` in select

Data used in example

```py
data = {
    "departments": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Dept 1",
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Dept 2",
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Dept 3",
    }],
    "cardgroups": [{
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Card 1",
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Card 2",
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Card 3",
    }],
    "doorgroups": [{
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Door 1",
    }, {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Door 2",
    }, {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Door 3",
    }],
}
```

There are 2 ways you can send data to backend

##### Using form

You can wrap the table with form with submit button and add name in select tag which would then make the data available in `request.form`

```py
<div class="row" id="tablediv">
  <div class="col">
    <form method="POST">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table"></table>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    const office_cardgroups = {{ data['cardgroups'] | safe }}
    const office_doorgroups = {{ data['doorgroups'] | safe }}

    const table = document.getElementById("table");
    const header = table.createTHead();
    var row = header.insertRow(0);
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "<b>Departments</b>";
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML =  "<b>Card Groups</b>";
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML =  "<b>Door Groups</b>";

    {% for department in data['departments'] %}
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "{{ department.name }}";
        var row_cardgroup = '<td className="select"><select name="cardgroups_{{ department.id }}">'

        for (const [key, cardgroup] of Object.entries(office_cardgroups)) {
            var row_cardgroup = row_cardgroup + '<option value=' + cardgroup['id'] + '>'+ cardgroup['name']+'</option>'
        }
        row_cardgroup = row_cardgroup + '</select></td>'

        row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = row_cardgroup

        var row_doorgroup = '<td className="select"><select name="doorgroups_{{ department.id }}">'

        for (const [key, doorgroup] of Object.entries(office_doorgroups)) {
            var row_doorgroup = row_doorgroup + '<option value=' + doorgroup['id'] + '>'+ doorgroup['name']+'</option>'
        }

        row_doorgroup = row_doorgroup +  '</selec></td>'

        row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = row_doorgroup

    {% endfor %}
</script>
```

```py
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    print(request.form)
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)
```

##### Using javascript

```
<div class="row" id="tablediv">
  <div class="col">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table"></table>
    <button id="send-data">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    const office_cardgroups = {{ data['cardgroups'] | safe }}
    const office_doorgroups = {{ data['doorgroups'] | safe }}

    const table = document.getElementById("table");
    const header = table.createTHead();
    var row = header.insertRow(0);
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "<b>Departments</b>";
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML =  "<b>Card Groups</b>";
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML =  "<b>Door Groups</b>";

    {% for department in data['departments'] %}
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "{{ department.name }}";
        var row_cardgroup = '<td className="select"><select id="cardgroups_{{ department.id }}">'

        for (const [key, cardgroup] of Object.entries(office_cardgroups)) {
            var row_cardgroup = row_cardgroup + '<option value=' + cardgroup['id'] + '>'+ cardgroup['name']+'</option>'
        }
        row_cardgroup = row_cardgroup + '</select></td>'

        row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = row_cardgroup

        var row_doorgroup = '<td className="select"><select id="doorgroups_{{ department.id }}">'

        for (const [key, doorgroup] of Object.entries(office_doorgroups)) {
            var row_doorgroup = row_doorgroup + '<option value=' + doorgroup['id'] + '>'+ doorgroup['name']+'</option>'
        }

        row_doorgroup = row_doorgroup +  '</selec></td>'

        row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = row_doorgroup

    {% endfor %}

    const departments = {{ data['departments'] | safe }}

    document.querySelector('#send-data').addEventListener('click', function() {
        const form_data = new FormData();
        departments.forEach(function(department) {
            let card_id = `cardgroups_${department.id}`;
            form_data.append(card_id, document.querySelector("#" + card_id).value);
            let door_id = `doorgroups_${department.id}`;
            form_data.append(door_id, document.querySelector("#" + door_id).value);
        })
        const url = 'http://localhost:5000/';
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
        // xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function ( response ) {};
        xhr.send( form_data );

        // using jQuery
        // $.ajax({
        //   url: url,
        //   data: form_data,
        //   processData: false,
        //   contentType: false,
        //   type: 'POST',
        //   success: function(data){
        //     alert(data);
        //   }
        // });
    });
</script>
```

```py
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    print(request.form)
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)
```

---

Improvement: Template just using jinja no javascript

```py
<div class="row" id="tablediv">
  <div class="col">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table">
      {% for department in data['departments'] %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ department.name }}</td>
          <td className="select">
            <select id="cardgroups_{{ department.id }}">
              {% for card in data['cardgroups'] %}
                  <option value='{{ card.id }}'>{{ card.name }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </td>
          <td className="select">
            <select id="doorgroups_{{ department.id }}">
              {% for door in data['doorgroups'] %}
                  <option value='{{ door.id }}'>{{ door.name }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: If you want to send on each select value separately you can `addEventListener` to each select.